# Creating a nested Map using Streams and Collectors

Tags: java, java-8, hashmap, java-stream, collectors

```
class QuizAnswers {
  List<MultipleChoiceAnswer> multipleChoiceAnswers;
  List<FreeResponseAnswer> freeResponseAnswers; //not relevant to this question
}

class MultipleChoiceAnswer {
  int questionId;
  // The index of the selected multiple choice question
  int answer_selection;
}
```

The input to my function is a `List<QuizAnswers>`.

I want to create an output of  `Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Long>>` that maps `<MultipleChoiceAnswer.questionId : <MultipleChoiceAnswer.answer_selection, total count of answer_selection>`. In other words, I want to create a nested map that maps each multiple choice quiz question to a map representing the total number of selections on each answer choice of that quiz question.

Suppose the input `List<QuizAnswers> quizAnswersList` as:

```
[ {questionId: 1, answer_selection: 2},    
  {questionId: 1, answer_selection:2},  
  {questionId: 1, answer_selection:3},   
  {questionId: 2, answer_selection:1} ]
```

Then I would want the output to be:

```
{1 : {2:2, 3:1}, 2: {1, 1}}
```

Because the question with `Id = 1` received two selections on answer choice `2` and `1` selection on answer choice `3` while the question with `Id=2` had `1` selection on answer choice `1`.

I have tried

```
quizAnswersList.stream()
            .map(
                quizAnswers ->
                    quizAnswers.getMultipleChoiceAnswers().stream()
                        .collect(
                            Collectors.groupingBy(
                                MultipleChoiceAnswer::getQuestionId,
                                Collectors.groupingBy(
                                    MultipleChoiceAnswer::getAnswerSelection,
                                    Collectors.counting()))));
```

Which is giving me an error. I am not very familiar with streams and collectors in general, so I'd love to learn how to do this correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to create an `output` of `Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Long>>` that maps <MultipleChoiceAnswer.questionId : <MultipleChoiceAnswer.answer_selection>, total count of answer_selection>.

You were close.  You just didn't `flatMap` the `MultipleChoiceAnswers` onto the stream so you had a nested stream and that was causing the problem.

Based on your edited question, here is what I came up with.

```
List<MultipleChoiceAnswer> mca =
        List.of(new MultipleChoiceAnswer(1, 2),
                new MultipleChoiceAnswer(1, 2),
                new MultipleChoiceAnswer(1, 3),
                new MultipleChoiceAnswer(2, 1));

// more could be added to the List.  You only provided one.
List<QuizAnswers> list = List.of(new QuizAnswers(mca));
```

- flatMap all the `MultipleChoice` lists
- group them by the `questionId`
- then subgroup them according to `AnswerSelection` and get a count
- then you get the Map output you requested.

```
Map<Integer,Map<Integer,Long>> map = list.stream()
        .flatMap(s -> s.getMultipleChoiceAnswers().stream())
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                MultipleChoiceAnswer::getQuestionId,
                Collectors.groupingBy(
                        MultipleChoiceAnswer::getAnswerSelection,
                        Collectors.counting())));

map.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

prints

```
1={2=2, 3=1}
2={1=1}
```

**Questions**

- how do you want to handle multiple `QuizAnswer` instances?
- how do you want to handle multiple `MulitpleChoiceAnswer` lists. You only provided one of each.

They could all be `flatmapped` together and processed as above.  But I think there could be some differences in the Answers (perhaps for different tests) which you don't want grouped and counted as the same.

**Example**

If I add the following to the `List<QuizAnswers>`

```
List<MultipleChoiceAnswer> mca2 =
List.of(new MultipleChoiceAnswer(1, 2),
        new MultipleChoiceAnswer(1, 2),
        new MultipleChoiceAnswer(5, 2),
        new MultipleChoiceAnswer(5, 2));
```

And process using the above solution, the output would be

```
1={2=4, 3=1}
2={1=1}
5={2=2}
```

Answer (score 1):

> input to my function is a `List<QuizAnswers>`. I want to create an output of `Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Long>>`

> I have tried `quizAnswersList.stream().map(quizAnswers -> ... )`
> which is giving me an error.

Method `map()` is an intermediate operation, i.e. it yields a *stream*. Therefore, if you try to assign the *stream-statement* you've listed to a variable of type `Map` you'll get a compilation error.

A stream pipeline needs to end with a terminal operation like `collect` in order to be executed and produce a result.

And before `collect()` you have to apply [`flatMap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap(java.util.function.Function)), which expects a *stream* as an argument, to transform the stream of `QuizAnswers` in to a stream of `MultipleChoiceAnswer`.

Your usage of *collectors* is correct and doesn't require any changes.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<QuizAnswers> quizAnswersList =
        List.of(new QuizAnswers(List.of(new MultipleChoiceAnswer(1, 2),
                                        new MultipleChoiceAnswer(1, 2))),
                new QuizAnswers(List.of(new MultipleChoiceAnswer(1, 3),
                                        new MultipleChoiceAnswer(2, 1))));

    Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Long>> totalCountOfAnswerSelectionByQuestion =
        quizAnswersList.stream()
            .flatMap(quizAnswers -> quizAnswers.getMultipleChoiceAnswers().stream())
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(MultipleChoiceAnswer::getQuestionId,
                        Collectors.groupingBy(MultipleChoiceAnswer::getAnswerSelection,
                            Collectors.counting())));

    System.out.println(totalCountOfAnswerSelectionByQuestion);
}
```

**Output**

```
{1={2=2, 3=1}, 2={1=1}}
```